in drracket version 8.12 how to trace a function?
my quesion is how can i trace a function in drracket version 8.12?
I have a guy who wrote the same code as me and his code works, so I think it's because our versions are different, so I want to know, in my version, what should I do to get the correct results?
here is my code:
(define (f x)
  (* x x))

(require racket/trace)
(trace f)

my
result, has error
other guy:
result, no error

You're using one of the HtDP student languages, which are very limited as to what they accept. The other guy is using a standard Racket language. You should too.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/choose-language.html
